# Rails path helpers not accepting a resource argument in rspec feature tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I started moving my RSpec `requests` specs into `features` to conform with the new pattern

However, when I `visit` a path helper in a `spec/features` example like this:

```
visit orgs_path(reader.org)
```

I get this error:

```
 Failure/Error: visit org_path(reader.org)
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orgs", :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>#<Org id: 1, name: "Org 1", description: "About org1", website: "", subdomain: "org1", created_at: "2014-12-29 03:33:52", updated_at: "2014-12-29 03:33:52">} missing required keys: [:id]
```

However, the example works fine when its in the `spec/requests` folder.

I can work around the issue by using this syntax:

```
visit orgs_path(id: reader.org.id)
```

But I don't want to refactor all my specs.  What's going on?

### Update

Here is my `routes.rb` where I'm using an optional `locale` scope

```
scope "(/:locale)", :locale =>  /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  resources :orgs, shallow: true do
    resources :invitations
    resources :memberships, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

`reader.org` is an instance of a `membership` factory which `belongs_to org`

I have this in `rails_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

I also include `spec/support/locales.rb` with these locale helpers

```
# see phoet's comment on https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255
# prevents the locale: <#ObjectID> problem where Rails thinks the object is the locale
class ActionView::TestCase::TestController
  def default_url_options(options={})
    get_default_url_options
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
  def default_url_options(options={})
    get_default_url_options
  end
end

def get_default_url_options
  {
    host: "app.dev",
    locale: I18n.locale || I18n.default_locale
  }
end
```

Comment: is this 'reader.org' your app url ? or something outside the app?

Comment: This seems related to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12178, although it's not clear why it works in the `requests` directory.

Comment: @PeterAlvin, I think you're right.  See my Update. I am using a `scope`in `routes.rb` and some locale helpers in `spec_helper.rb`

Comment: In reading through https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255 again, I think my version of phoet's monkey patch was only working on request specs. phoet offers a revised solution but I like the simplicity and overt nature of deivid-rodriguez's `config.before(:each, type: :feature) { default_url_options[:locale] = I18n.default_locale
}` solution